# Does chess engine Stockfish remember already performed calculations within one session?

Tags: engines

Let's say I call Stockfish via

```
> position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
>'go movetime 500';
```

Now, after Stockfish has finished the analysis, what happens if I call stockfish again with the same position?

```
> position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
> go movetime 500
```

Will Stockfish build on the already performed analysis and simply go deeper? Or will it start the analysis anew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Stockfish will go deeper if the hash is large enough to make a difference. The default value is 16 MB which is not a lot. After increasing the hash you likely see that the second time the search depth reached after 500 ms is higher than the first time you let Stockfish calculate.

```
setoption name Hash value 256
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By now, I also observed that when I called the Stockfish engine multiple times on the same position, the analysis depth increased - meaning Stockfish remembered earlier analysis results and built on those to improve the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

One UCI session you mean? To make reproducible experiments or test above, you can compare/contrast multiple calls, by using the UCI purge hash.

"setoption name Clear Hash"